# want to get screen point on render texture camera unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am making sniper game, I have 2 cameras, one is rendering whole environment, and second one is in scope of the gun, which has high zoom quality.
I am able to show, enemy point on screen through main camera. and it shows proper on main camera, but in scope camera(2nd camera), it not showing properly. I want to show these points exactly same as enemy is.
here is my script to show point so far. I am attaching screen shots, first one is for scope camera and does not showing proper place, and 2nd one is for main camera, showing at proper place (Red circle is pointing) [image: Red circle is pointing]

```c#
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class identity_shower : MonoBehaviour {
    public Texture tex;
    public GameObject helt;
    public bool target_is_high =false;
    private int counter_for_high = -1;
    private int counter_for_low  = -1;
    private int counter_value = 50;
    private bool bool_for_high = false;
    private bool bool_for_low = false;
    private Camera scope_cam_active;
    private RectTransform rectTransform;
    private Vector2 uiOFFset;



    // Update is called once per frame

    void OnGUI()
    {
        GameObject[] objs = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("enemy_soldier");
        if( objs.Length<=0 )
        {
             return;
        }
        if (bool_for_high) 
        {
             Vector2 pos_to_display = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint (this.transform.position);
             GUI.DrawTexture (new Rect(pos_to_display.x-10.0f,(Screen.height- pos_to_display.y)-40.0f,15,15),tex);
        }
    }

    public void show_your_identity()
    {
        if (target_is_high) {
            if (counter_for_high >= counter_value) 
            {
                 return;
            }
            counter_for_high = counter_for_high + 1;
            if (counter_for_high >= counter_value) 
            {
                 bool_for_high = true;      
             }
        } else if(!target_is_high)
        {
             if (counter_for_low >= counter_value) 
             {
                return;
             }
             counter_for_low = counter_for_low + 1;
             if (counter_for_low >= counter_value) 
             {
                 bool_for_low = true;
             }
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: I guess when you are drawing the red circle, you draw it based on main Camera, not your scope Camera ?

Comment: I tried to draw through scope cam.. but fails.. did'nt work.

Comment: Because 2nd scope cam is rendering at render texture which is place in gun scope.. i think its due to render texture but not confirmed

Comment: Lets say you have 4x zoom on the scope camera. Adjust your main camera for 4x zoom. Make the calculations on main Camera for 4x zoom. Will you get new numbers for this line ? `GUI.DrawTexture (new Rect(pos_to_display.x-10.0f,(Screen.height- pos_to_display.y)-40.0f,15,15),tex);` If so; when scope is activated use that numbers, you can still draw it based on main Camera. But your numbers will be different. At least thats how i think might work.